# Hi I am looking for a solution to convert set of docx files to pdf in solaris environment

Tags: unix, pdf, solaris, ghostscript, docx

How to convert docx file to pdf using ghostscript in solaris environment. or Is there any builtin Commands available in either ghostscript/solaris? please help.

Comment: Do you have to stick with Ghostscript? You could use LibreOffice from command line.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript does not read docx or similar. Your best bet is probably Open/Libre Office.

If you are wedded to using Ghostscript then you need to convert the docx file to something Ghostscript can read (PostScript, PDF, XPS or PCL).

Probably the easiest way to do that is to open in OpenOffice and print to PostScript. Or you could just export to PDF while you are there.....

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway we can batch convert the process using Open/Libre Office.

Comment: I have no idea, I know very little about either application.